# Search box in react-leaflet looks wrong

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

[image]

It looks like that when it is supposed to be a button that you press to open.
I am using react-leaflet with mapzen's leaflet-geocoder.

```
import { MapControl } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet-geocoder-mapzen'

export default class SearchBox extends MapControl {
  componentWillMount() {
    const searchBox = L.control.geocoder(<API-KEY>)
    this.leafletElement = searchBox
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the relevant CSS files as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-geocoder-mapzen? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-geocoder-mapzen/1.4.1/leaflet-geocoder-mapzen.css">`

Answer (score 0):

I added some styling in my CSS that made the search box look somewhat better — that's my fix for now, at least.

```
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

.leaflet-pelias-control, .leaflet-pelias-input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.leaflet-pelias-search-icon {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.leaflet-pelias-close {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.leaflet-pelias-close::after {
  content:'Clear search';
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 2px;
}

.leaflet-top, .leaflet-left {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Could you explain more about your context ? Does this fix address the question directly? Or do you have different assumptions? It would also be great to get some explanation about your contribution: What does it fix exactly? What to expect ?

Answer (score 0):

For leaflet-control-geocoder, what worked for me, was to add the following to index.css:

```
@import "~leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css";
```

So for leaflet-geocoder-mapzen I'm guessing (untested):

```
@import "~leaflet-geocoder-mapzen/1.9.4/leaflet-geocoder-mapzen.css";
```

or similar

FYI

Tilde (~) used in conjunction with webpack means that a lookup is performed against node_modules to resolve the path.
see [stackoverflow explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113870/what-is-the-tilde-doing-in-this-javascript-import)