# What is the ~ (tilde) doing in this javascript import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the App.tsx taken from the fountain-webapp typescript MVC sample (http://fountainjs.io/), the import contains the following line:

```
import {IDispatch} from '~react-redux~redux';
```

Visual Studio 2017 underlines this line ("cannot find module") however it does work in the browser.  I've never seen this syntax before and don't know what it's attempting to do?

There's an open ticket mentioning it here: https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-react/issues/70

Comment: I understand the {braces} but not the "from '~"

Comment: Looks like it's a Webpack thing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39535760/215552

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typescript file and the `import` looks like a `typings` generated module IMO.

I'm not well versed in typescript but `typings` <strike>probably</strike> uses this `~` (tilde) format to check for module dependencies in a particular namespace.

According to [Blake Embrey](https://github.com/blakeembrey), in [this](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/528) thread on the typings github repo:

> It's namespacing for dependencies.

Comment: Nice find.  From reading that thread it does seem like it's a syntax for walking down the tree of typings files.  I'll leave the bounty open for a little while to see if anyone else bites...

Comment: Yes, this is from `typings`. In post ts@2.0 code you should probably use `@types/redux` and just do `import { IDispatch } from 'redux'`

Comment: Although I can't find any documentation whatsoever for this, I'm accepting this as the likely correct answer.

Answer (score 39):

Tilde (`~`) used in conjunction with [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) means that a lookup is performed against `node_modules` to resolve the path.

In other words, it is a predefined [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) that resolves to `node_modules`.

```
import { IDispatch } from '~react-redux~redux';
```

is equivalent to

```
import { IDispatch } from 'relative_path_to_node_modules/react-redux~redux';
```

---

EDIT: Unfortunately, I can't cite any documentation about this, it is based on experience, you're welcome to edit this post with a more accurate description.

Now I've noticed the `~redux` part as well, so you might want to check out the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226498/2762747), because I'm puzzled there as well.

Comment: Can you cite any documentation about this?

Comment: Is there a module called `react-redux~redux`? Because how does this explain the second `~`, also I couldn't find any such package in the json which was exported here: https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-react/blob/master/generators/todoMVC/modules/index.js

Comment: good point, I haven't noticed the ~redux part. Now I'm completely puzzled as well. I'll update if I find more info, for now I reference your answer.

Comment: Also, I think you need to manually add an alias to resolve your lookup path to `node_modules` like `alias: {'~': path.resolve(__dirname)}`