# What does the tilde (~) mean in Node.js's "require"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm reading through the source code for the game "Screeps" (trying to reverse-engineer how it executes user-provided scripts in a safe way, to use in games of my own), and I've come across a line I don't understand.

Line 10 in [this file](https://github.com/screeps/engine/blob/master/src/utils.js) reads:

```
    driver = require('~runtime-driver');
```

What does the tilde mean here? This doesn't seem to refer to a local file *or* a separate package, so where is it locating the driver?

The engine runs on node, and here are the dependencies from `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@screeps/pathfinding": "^0.4.16",
    "bulk-require": "^0.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "q": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-traceur": "^0.17.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "jasmine": "^3.3.0"
  },
```

(Reading this, could it be a babel thing?)

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's similar to import: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113870/what-is-the-tilde-doing-in-this-javascript-import

Comment: I think that the tilde means it's looking for the file in the [home directory of the interpreter \(modules\)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=shell-tilde-substitution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Webpack thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226632/893780).

For this project, what `~runtime-driver` resolves to is defined [here](https://github.com/screeps/driver/blob/b152aadbc09b8e09b27f0c6afef1958a14dfdd86/webpack.config.js):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~runtime-driver': require.resolve('./lib/runtime/runtime-driver')
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Follow-up, how does it know to use the alias given in a different repo? Does webpack grab all the webpack config from all the _other_ things you import before doing its bundle?

Comment: @TimLeach I got the impression that even though there are different repo's, everything should be installed inside the same directory (or will end up in the same directory after installation or setting up). I think Webpack itself is git-agnostic.